# error while implementing react-native-tab-navigator

Tags: react-native

i am implementing react native tab navigator as :

```
 <TabNavigator>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
    title="Home"
    renderIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    badgeText="1"
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'home' })}>
    {homeView}
  </TabNavigator.Item>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
    title="Profile"
    renderIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
    renderBadge={() => <CustomBadgeView />}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'profile' })}>
    {profileView}
  </TabNavigator.Item>
</TabNavigator>
```

This is the code i am implementing , as they have shown in their [documentation] , But this is showing me certain error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `TabNavigator`

.
 Kindly correct me , where i am doing wrong

Comment: have you add react-navigation and import the library?

Comment: yes , but tab navigator i am importing from "react-native-tab-navigator "

Comment: Are you using webpack? Include how you import the elements because it might be an importing error.

Comment: i am importing like " import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';"